# Highlight entire row if all cell values are the same

Tags: excel

Or, if easier, highlight the row if all cell values are not the same.

I'll have four (or six) columns of data and need to see where any differences occur across each row occur. I tried to follow a youtube vid on conditional formatting but couldn't alter it to work. I'm on excel for mac v16.

Comment: To format all cells in a row if they have the same value, you can use the following formula as your condition: `=COUNTIF($A1:$F1,$A1)=6`  (I assumed data is in columns `A` to `F`)

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad Great! Add as an answer and I'll accept. Also I noticed that if I change the data, getting the rule to reapply seems I need to futz within Manage Rules.

Comment: You mean if you type in different values in the cells? That shouldn't be the case. You did select the entire range you want the condition applied to when creating the rule?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To format all cells in a row if they have the same value, you can use the following formula as your condition:

```
=COUNTIF($A1:$F1,$A1)=6
```

(Assuming data is in columns `A` to `F`)